# Asset folder contains PDF in Bengali Language and when uploading this PDF to Firebase it returns error as images

Tags: android, firebase

I'm working on a project to upload PDF from asset to Firebase Storage, Some of PDFs are in Bengali Language when uploading these pdfs it returns error as "images".

> Here is my code

```
private boolean listAssetFiles(String path) {
        String [] list;
        try {
            list = getAssets().list(path);
            if (list.length > 0) {
                // This is a folder
                for (String file : list) {
                    if (!listAssetFiles(path + "/" + file))
                        return false;
                    else {
                        InputStream inputStream = getAssets().open(file);

                        ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        int nRead;
                        byte[] data = new byte[inputStream.available()];

                        while ((nRead = inputStream.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
                            buffer.write(data, 0, nRead);
                        }
                        byte [] arr = buffer.toByteArray();
                        storageReference.child("PDFs").putBytes(arr).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                                Log.d(TAG, "Success = true: ");
                            }
                        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                Log.d(TAG, "Success = false ");
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Exception: "+e.getMessage());
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

This is error it returns.

```
D/ContentValues: Exception: images
```

Comment: Don't post images of text

Comment: Sir this is the exception, I'm getting

Comment: Then post it as text, not image. That's my point.

Comment: kindly check it now.

Comment: Which statement is causing that exception? I think your listing and such. Not the uploading. Use also try-catch around uploading code.

Comment: `listAssetFiles(String path) ` A function with that name should only list. Not upload or whatever. Pretty confusing.

Comment: Is the file name in Bengali language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide path with the file name. 
You can try this **modified code snippet.**

```
private boolean listAssetFiles(String path) {
        String[] list;
        try {
            list = getAssets().list(path);
            if (list.length > 0) {
                for (String file : list) {
                    if (!listAssetFiles(path + "/" + file))
                        return false;
                    else {

                        InputStream inputStream = getAssets().open(path+"/"+file);
                        int size = inputStream.available();
                        ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                        int nRead;
                        byte[] arr = new byte[size];

                        while ((nRead = inputStream.read(arr, 0, arr.length)) != -1) {
                            buffer.write(arr, 0, nRead);
                        }

                        byte[] pdf = buffer.toByteArray();


                        storageReference.child("PDFs").child(file).putBytes(pdf).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Uploaded: "+file, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Log.d(TAG, "Success = true: ");
                            }
                        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed: "+file, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Log.d(TAG, "Success = false: ");
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "listAssetFiles Failure: "+e.getMessage());
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```